# IDA Pro macOS kernel debugging and lldb support

Tags: ida, lldb, kernel, macos

I'm trying to revers some kexts on macOS and I can't find a way to achieve the same level of debugging you can do on Windows kernel with IDA and WinDBG. Is there a way to add support for lldb? Or can it be done without lldb?

I've tried the VMWare gdb stub, but IDA can't map the memory right.